# Side lobe reduction

Tags: image-processing, matlab, python

How can side-lobes be reduced in an Level-1 SAR image in Spatial Domain?The input here in this problem is an complex SAR image?which parameters(like amplitude) of SAR image should be considered mainly while removing side lobes at image level?

Comment: Your question makes no sense: "how can I do signal processing without doing signal processing".

Comment: The input I have is an Image,should I convert it to any domain before removing side lobes because Im quiet new to signal processing

Comment: that is quite different from what you asked in the question? Could you **edit** your question and ask with way more background on what 1. you're currently doing,  what you're trying to achieve, 3. the specific hurdle you're facing right now. Right now, your question is simply inanswerable!

Comment: There are techniques to reducing sidelobes in most applications (I can't speak to yours in particular) but they come at the cost of additional main lobe width. Is that something your application can afford to sacrifice?

Comment: @AnalogEE ..Yes to a certain extent.All I have is an complex SAR image as an input,I need to remove the strong scatters which happen to be side lobes.Many scientific papers related to side-lobe reduction give information on reducing them at signal level..How can those be applied at image level..or is there any techniques or ideas you would like to suggest?

Comment: @Marcus Müller,I have edited the question, Im not getting proper results when I simply try to remove as side lobe using python opencv etc,should any signal level information be used in this regards?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reduce sidelobes and are willing to accept lobe width increase, I'd suggest a Taylor window. Applying it to an image instead of a time-domain signal should not be an issue, so long as it is spatial sidelobes, not temporal ones, that you wish to suppress. Images are just spatial signals, so you can apply this filter in the X and Y dimension of the image I think (may require decomposition of some kind so you don't end up filtering twice).

https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/taylorwin.html